# Eazfuscator: disable sn.exe invocation

Tags: c#, obfuscation, signing, strongname, eazfuscator

Obfuscating a project with a strong name fails when attempting to use delayed signing.

We'd like to manually call signtool.exe *after* obfuscation on our CI server using the certificate installed there by reference to its fingerprint.

it seems that Eazfuscator sees that the assembly has a strong name and then attempts to resign the obfuscated assembly using sn.exe, failing since the configured .snk only contains the public key.

We're using Eazfuscator by conditionally referencing the Nuget package and would like to keep it that way (not having to  switch to manual Eazfuscator.NET.exe invocation)

Also: we purchased a site license in 2020. The included 1-year period of free upgrades has passed, so we're currently stuck with the 2020 release.

Comment: Eazfuscator.NET automatically handles the scenario with delayed-signed assemblies, so normally this should not pose a problem. Your best bet is to try out the newer Eazfuscator.NET version, it should work out of the box in that regard.